# Populating data using formula in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have excel workbook which contains two sheets, Sheet1 is with Leave approved data and other with employee data. I need to populate approved leave in employee data using formula. Please guide on this. I have attached sample input and output for your reference.

Input:
[image]

Required Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your Input data starts on cell A1 of a sheet called "Input" and your desired output is on a new sheet starting on cell A1. Place this formula in cell C2 (for the first empty part of the grid) and fill down-right.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Input!$B:$B,$A2,Input!$D:$D,"<="&C$1,Input!$F:$F,">="&C$1)>0,"L","")
```

Column B is a simple VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Input!$B:$C,2,false)
```

Comment: -Thanks for your reply and you missed "Input" in center and corrected formula is =IF(COUNTIFS(Input!$B:$B,$A2,Input!$D:$D,"<="&C$1,Input!$F:$F,">="&C$1)>0,"L","")